# Is there a way to split and copy rows where there is a carriage return?

Tags: vba

I have a spread sheet with a lot of columns and rows. Within those columns there are cells where data has been combined using a carriage return, 
The top screenshots the data, the first row has 2 carriage returns in and back up name has 1 Row 2 has a carriage return in the code column
I want this to change to the table below it

[image]

The below code, splits the cells and pastes them on the end. I then move the original data + 1 column into a new workbook. Paste the split out value back into correct column. Then paste this into a new workbook.
Repeat until the additional columns are gone

```
    Sub SplitCarriageReturnsCostCodes()


    Sheets("Booking Details").Select

'This will cells where there is a carriage return

    Dim splitVals As Variant
    Dim totalVals As Long
    Dim CellstoSplit As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long          'Makes the last row check the last cell with data in'


    LastRow = Worksheets("Booking Details").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    'Set range to split:
    Set CellstoSplit = Range("AG2", "AG2" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In CellstoSplit
    cell.Activate
    splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
    totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 17), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 17 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
    'Pastes them on the end, from range of cell selected plus a number of cells count
    Next cell

End Sub

Sub CreateTabCostCodes()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)   'Adding sheet after all tabs
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Temp Sheet 1"     'Gives new sheet a name

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)   'Adding sheet after all tabs
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Booking Details New"     'Gives new sheet a name


End Sub

Sub CopyandPasteCostCodes()
'
        'Dim I As Integer                            'Set I name as a variable
        'I = 1                                       'I = 1
        'Do While I <= 100


        Dim ColCount As Integer                     'Sets column count as an integer
        Dim I As Integer                            'Set I as interget
        intCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Booking Details").UsedRange.Columns.Count
                                                    'counts column in my range I just created
        ColCount = intCol - 49                      'column count minus the pre existing columns
        Do While I <= ColCount                      'do while I is equal to or less than column count

        Dim LastRow As Long                     'Makes the last row check the last cell with data in'
        LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column E = 5, count columns as per a Vlookup'

        Sheets("Booking Details").Select
        Range("A2", "AX2" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Temp Sheet 1").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("AX1", "AX1" & LastRow).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Cut
        Range("AG1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A1", "AW1" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Booking Details New").Select
        Range("A100000").Select              'Find empty cell at bottom
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select          'Goes from bottom till it find data, xlup = go up'
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select      'In this 1,0 then 1 is rows to offset, pastes below the copied data'.
                                            '0 is columns.
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Deletes column AW and moves the data along so I can pick it up again

        Sheets("Booking Details").Select
        'Columns("AW:AW").Select               'Before I fixed notes column
        Columns("AX:AX").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        I = I + 1                   'Add 1 to I up to my number above
    Loop

    Sheets("Booking Details New").Select
    Range("Z2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("AG:Ag").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub Copy_HeadersCostCodes()
'
' Copies headers from booking details to new tab

    Sheets("Booking Details").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("AP1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking Details New").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Fixes a header that formats badly

    Sheets("Booking Details New").Select
    Range("Z1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AG1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub


Public Sub DeleteBlankRowsCostCodes()

'This deletes any row where there is a blank in column AA in the Bookings new tab'

    Dim lLRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Booking Details New") 'Select temp sheet tab'
     lLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Looks from top to end of data in first column, hence rows.count, 1'
    .Range("AG:AG").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
    .Range("AG2:AG" & lLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
     .AutoFilterMode = False
     End With

End Sub
```

It works but it feels heavy handed. Still new to VBA, learning on the go

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far? You're going to need to do some iteration over the rows, check for the presence of the carriage return, and then use some logic to insert a new row if carriage return found, parsing the contents of the cell(s) containing the CR into the newly inserted row.

Comment: I think you need to accept some of your previous question's answers and upvote answers to your questions to get some help. you seem to just ask a question and then give no feedback.  Also, You need to show some sort of effort in doing this yourself (i.e. post your code).

Comment: I have got to the point where I have a solution but I am hoping there is more elegant way of doing this!